# Simplify $\frac{x^{-6}+y^{-6}}{\left( x^{2}+y^{-2} \right)y^{-4}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Simplify

$\frac{x^{-6}+y^{-6}}{\left( x^{2}+y^{-2} \right)y^{-4}}$

Attempt: I start by multiplying with $x^6y^6$ on both numerator and denominator. Then substitute x^2=a and y^2=b for an easier read. But that only gets me to

$\frac{\left( a+b \right)\left( a^{2}-ab+b^{2} \right)}{a^{3}\left( ab+1 \right)}$

I'm stuck.

a) How do I solve this problem
b) How do I solve these kinds of problems in general – what is a good "strategy"?

Comment: Your attempt is good at the beginning, but I think there are some factors missing when you get to your second fraction involving $a,b$...

Comment: Ordinarily, factoring is the opposite of simplification. I would have just left it in the correct form that you evidently passed through, namely $(x^6+y^6)/(x^6(x^2y^2+1))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps a good strategy would be to make it so that there are no negative exponents. In this case, first we could distribute the $y^{-4}$ in the denominator. So we have

$\frac{x^{-6}+y^{-6}}{(x^2+y^{-2})y^{-4}}=\frac{x^{-6}+y^{-6}}{x^2y^{-4}+y^{-6}}$.

Then, to eliminate all of the negative exponents, we multiply the whole fraction by $\frac{x^6y^6}{x^6y^6}$. Thus we have

$\frac{(x^{-6}+y^{-6})x^6y^6}{(x^2y^{-4}+y^{-6})x^6y^6}=\frac{y^6+x^6}{x^8y^2+x^6}$.

Everyone has their own idea of what makes something more simplified. This is one way of going about it. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much to be done.  You could distribute the denominator and notice the $y^{-6}$s:
$$\frac{x^{-6}+y^{-6}}{(x^2+y^{-2})y^{-4}}=\frac{x^{-6}+y^{-6}}{x^2y^{-4}+y^{-6}}=1+\frac{x^{-6}-x^2y^{-4}}{x^2y^{-4}+y^{-6}}$$ but I am not sure this is progress.  Are you sure the two exponents on the $x$'s are of opposite signs?